# Need help to map two arrays with objects together bases on proprty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to create multiple lists based on two different arrays. I have an array called categoryList and termsList. I want to group the terms list based on a property to the categoryList array.

```
const categoriesList = [
   { name: 'Categories', slug: 'category' },
   { name: 'Tags', slug: 'post_tag' }
];
```

and

```
const termsList = [
   { id: 1, taxonomy: 'category', name: 'First category' },
   { id: 2, taxonomy: 'category', name: 'Second category' },
   { id: 3, taxonomy: 'post_tag', name: 'First tag' },
   { id: 4, taxonomy: 'post_tag', name: 'Second tag' }
];
```

The property slug in the categoriesList always has the same value as the taxonomy property in the termsList.
What i'm trying to accomplish is this within a React component:

```
<h1>Categories</h1>
<ul>
   <li>First category</li>
   <li>Second category</li>
</ul>

<h1>Tags</h1>
<ul>
   <li>First tag</li>
   <li>Second tag</li>
</ul>
```

I don't know how to do this. Some help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: So you want to split the termList based on the taxonamy value property into two arrays? Please show us what is desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a small working React example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  // Accepts an array of terms, and a slug
  getTermList(terms, slug) {
    return terms

      // It `filter`s out the terms by slug value
      .filter(({ taxonomy }) => taxonomy === slug)

      // And then `map`s those filtered values to <li>s
      .map(({ name }) => <li>{name}</li>);
  }
  
  render() {
 
   const { categories, terms } = this.props;
 
   return (

     // `map` over the categories, and return a
     // list of terms based on the slug value
     categories.map(({ name, slug }) => {
       return (
        <div class="category">
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <ul>
           {this.getTermList(terms, slug)}
        </ul>
        </div>
       );
     })
   );
  }
}

const categories = [
  { name: 'Categories', slug: 'category' },
  { name: 'Tags', slug: 'post_tag' }
];

const terms = [
  { id: 1, taxonomy: 'category', name: 'First category' },
  { id: 2, taxonomy: 'category', name: 'Second category' },
  { id: 3, taxonomy: 'post_tag', name: 'First tag' },
  { id: 4, taxonomy: 'post_tag', name: 'Second tag' }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <App categories={categories} terms={terms} />,
  document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

```css
.category { margin: 1em; }
h1 { font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: 600; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to make it work:

```js
const categoriesList = [
   { name: 'Categories', slug: 'category' },
   { name: 'Tags', slug: 'post_tag' }
];

const termsList = [
   { id: 1, taxonomy: 'category', name: 'First category' },
   { id: 2, taxonomy: 'category', name: 'Second category' },
   { id: 3, taxonomy: 'post_tag', name: 'First tag' },
   { id: 4, taxonomy: 'post_tag', name: 'Second tag' }
];

const result = 
    categoriesList
      .map(cl => ({
        [cl.name]: termsList.filter(tl => tl.taxonomy === cl.slug),
      }))
      .reduce((a, b) => ({ ...a, ...b }));

console.log(res);

// Result of console.log(res);
// 
// {
//  Categories: [
//   {
//    id: 1,
//    taxonomy: 'category',
//    name: 'First category',
//   },
//   {
//    id: 2,
//    taxonomy: 'category',
//    name: 'Second category',
//   },
//  ],
//  Tags: [
//   {
//    id: 3,
//    taxonomy: 'post_tag',
//    name: 'First tag',
//   },
//   {
//    id: 4,
//    taxonomy: 'post_tag',
//    name: 'Second tag',
//   },
//  ],
// };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jose A. Ayllón. How would i go about turning this in to html within a react render return function?